# Links within littleBoxes JQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add this neat header to my site: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/05/18/little-boxes-menu-with-jquery/

The one problem is that the javascript was making all links animate in the same way as the little boxes, so any links I included within the header would become animated. I found one thread here on Stack Overflow that offered some solutions. After finding one that appeared to work, I discovered that the boxes no longer animate once expanded. When you click on the box div to have it close, it will instead refresh the page.

I'd like to find a way to include links without compromising the animated effect.

Here's the Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    /* object to save the initial positions of each box */
    var divinfo = {"initial": []};
    /* index of the selected / clicked box */
    var current = -1;

    /* we save the index,top and left of each box */
                $('#littleBoxes > div','staffer').each(function(){
                 $('staffer').removeClass('#littleBoxes a').addClass('#staffer a');
        var $this = $(this);
        var initial = {
                    'index' : $this.index(),
                    'top'     : $this.css('top'),
                    'left'     : $this.css('left')
        };
        divinfo.initial.push(initial);
    });

    /* click event for the anchors inside of the boxes */
    $('#littleBoxes a').bind('click',function(e){
            var $this         = $(this);
            var $currentBox    = $this.parent();
            /* set a z-index lower than all the other boxes,
            to see the other boxes animation on the top*/
            $currentBox.css('z-index','1');

            /* if we are clicking on an expanded box: */
            if(current == $currentBox.index()){
                /* put it back (decrease width, height,
                and set the top and left back)
                the previous positions are saved in the divinfo obj*/
                $currentBox.stop().animate({
                        'top'  : divinfo.initial[$currentBox.index()].top,
                        'left' : divinfo.initial[$currentBox.index()].left,
                        'width'  : '90px',
                        'height' : '90px'
                },800,'easeOutBack').find('.boxcontent').fadeOut();

                $('#littleBoxes > div').not($currentBox).each(function(){
                    var $ele         = $(this);
                    var elemTop     = divinfo.initial[$ele.index()].top;
                    var elemLeft     = divinfo.initial[$ele.index()].left;
                    $ele.stop().show().animate({
                        'top'         : elemTop,
                        'left'        : elemLeft,
                        'opacity'    : 1
                    },800);
                });
                current = -1;
            }
            /* if we are clicking on a small box : */
            else{
                /* randomly animate all the other boxes.
                Math.floor(Math.random()*601) - 150 creates a random
                number between -150 and 450. This range is considering
                the initial lefts/tops of the elements. It's not the exact
                range, since we would have to calculate the range
                based on each one of the boxes. Anyway, it fits our needs...
                */
                $('#littleBoxes > div').not($currentBox).each(function(){
                    var $ele = $(this);
                    $ele.stop().animate({
                        'top' : (Math.floor(Math.random()*601) - 150) +'px',
                        'left': (Math.floor(Math.random()*601) - 150) +'px',
                        'opacity':0
                    },800,function(){
                        $(this).hide();
                    });
                });

                /* expand the clicked one;
                also, fadeIn the content (boxcontent)
                */
                var newwidth     = 945;
                var newheight     = 375;
                $currentBox.stop().animate({
                    'top'     : '0px',
                    'left'    : '0px',
                    'width' : newwidth +'px',
                    'height': newheight+'px'
                },800,'easeOutBack',function(){
                    current = $currentBox.index();
                    $(this).find('.boxcontent').fadeIn();
                });
            }
            e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.littleBoxes {
    width:1000px;
    height:343px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;

}

.littleBoxes > div {
    position:absolute;
    width:90px;
    height:90px;
    text-align:center;
    border:2px solid #F7F7FF;
    overflow:hidden;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #555;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #555;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #555;
    background-position:center center;
    z-index:999;
}

.littleBoxes div a.logobox {

text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 120%;
font-weight: normal;
font-family: Oswald, sans serif;
letter-spacing: 1px;
display: block;
line-height: 90px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #F7F7FF;
background-image: linear-gradient(right bottom, #111111 5%, #2A2D34 50%, #111111 95%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right bottom, #111111 5%, #2A2D34 50%, #111111 95%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right bottom, #111111 5%, #2A2D34 50%, #111111 95%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right bottom, #111111 5%, #2A2D34 50%, #111111 95%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right bottom, #111111 5%, #2A2D34 50%, #111111 95%);
background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, right bottom, left top, color-stop(0.05, #111111), color-stop(0.5, #2A2D34), color-stop(0.95, #111111) );
outline: none;

}

.littleBoxes div.boxcontent{

    height:380px;
    text-align:left;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:100%;
    color: #333232;
    background-color:#F7F7FF;
    border:2px solid #F7F7FF;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 3px #777;
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 3px #777;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 3px #777;
    opacity:0.9;
    display:none;
}

.boxcontent .boxinfo {

display: inline-block;
background: #F7F7FF;
width: 46%;
height: 200px;
text-align: justify;
overflow-y: auto;
padding: 10px;
margin-top: -20px;

}

.boxcontent .boxstaff {

float: right;
width: 46%;

}

.boxinfo b {
  font-size: 105%;
  text-shadow: #333232 0 1px 1px;
  background: linear-gradient(right bottom, #111111 5%, #2A2D34 50%, #111111 95%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.boxcontent div a {
display: inline;
background: transparent;

}


.bg1, .bg2, .bg3, .bg4{
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.bg1{
    background-image:url(../images/1.jpg);
}
.bg2{
    background-image:url(../images/2.jpg);
}
.bg3{
    background-image:url(../images/3.jpg);
}
.bg4{
    background-image:url(../images/4.jpg);
}
.bg5{
    background-image:url(../images/5.jpg);
}

#staffer h1 {
  display: block;
  margin-top: -20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
text-shadow: #333232 0 1px 1px;
   background: linear-gradient(right bottom, #111111 5%, #2A2D34 50%, #111111 95%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

#staffer h2 {

display: block;
width: 120px;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin-top: -25px;


}

#staffer img {
  margin: -20px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); filter: grayscale(100%);
transition: all, 1s;
  -moz-transition: all, 1s;
  -webkit-transition: all, 1s;

}

#staffer img:hover {

-webkit-filter: grayscale(0%); filter: grayscale(0%);

}
```

Here's the current demo: http://codepen.io/karlen/pen/RNeqrm

Comment: Can you please provide a complete demo of your code?

Comment: I'm sorry. I completely forgot to do so. Here's a link to the current header: http://thoseleftbehind.jcink.net/index.php?act=idx

Comment: Please, also include you HTML here.

Comment: This might be better: http://codepen.io/scnumbah82/pen/ZYqqgK

Comment: Yes it's better, but your menu doesn't function at all.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not functioning there when it functions on the site itself.

Comment: I've updated it. You didn't include the jQuery. Here is the updated *pen*: http://codepen.io/karlen/pen/RNeqrm

Comment: Thank you! I'll include that in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I get it to work.

I just took the original(working) code, compared with your code and found some differences.

**First**, I don't know why, but you used the `bind()` method instead of the `on()`. The latter one is the preferred choice as per the official docs of jQuery.

**Second**, you changed the sizes of the container, which should be opened when you click the menu. This is a correct change.

**Lastly**, the main change which was the cause of the failure was the following piece of code. You changed this:

```
$('#littleBoxes > div').each(function() {
```

by this:

```
$('#littleBoxes > div', 'staffer').each(function() { 
     $('staffer').removeClass('#littleBoxes a').addClass('#staffer a');
```

There are some issues.

1. You break the code by altering the selector on the first line.
2. Your selectors are invalid on both lines as you don't have a tag called `staffer`

After fixing the issues I get it to work.

**Update**
Also I just noticed that clicking on the links inside of the opened content is also animates the menu, which is unwanted (IMO). So I changed the selector to target not all the links, but the ones which have the `.logobox` class.

*And here is **the working result**.*

```js
$(function() {
  /* object to save the initial positions of each box */
  var divinfo = {
    "initial": []
  };
  /* index of the selected / clicked box */
  var current = -1;
  /* we save the index,top and left of each box */
  $('#littleBoxes > div').each(function() {
    $('#staffer').removeClass('#littleBoxes a').addClass(
      '#staffer a');
    var $this = $(this);
    var initial = {
      'index': $this.index(),
      'top': $this.css('top'),
      'left': $this.css('left')
    };
    divinfo.initial.push(initial);
  });
  /* click event for the anchors inside of the boxes */
  $('#littleBoxes a.logobox').bind('click', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $currentBox = $this.parent();
    /* set a z-index lower than all the other boxes,
        to see the other boxes animation on the top*/
    $currentBox.css('z-index', '1');
    /* if we are clicking on an expanded box: */
    if (current == $currentBox.index()) {
      /* put it back (decrease width, height,
          and set the top and left back)
          the previous positions are saved in the divinfo obj*/
      $currentBox.stop().animate({
        'top': divinfo.initial[$currentBox.index()]
          .top,
        'left': divinfo.initial[$currentBox.index()]
          .left,
        'width': '90px',
        'height': '90px'
      }, 800, 'easeOutBack').find('.boxcontent').fadeOut();
      $('#littleBoxes > div').not($currentBox).each(
        function() {
          var $ele = $(this);
          var elemTop = divinfo.initial[$ele.index()]
            .top;
          var elemLeft = divinfo.initial[$ele.index()]
            .left;
          $ele.stop().show().animate({
            'top': elemTop,
            'left': elemLeft,
            'opacity': 1
          }, 800);
        });
      current = -1;
    }
    /* if we are clicking on a small box : */
    else {
      /* randomly animate all the other boxes.
          Math.floor(Math.random()*601) - 150 creates a random
          number between -150 and 450. This range is considering
          the initial lefts/tops of the elements. It's not the exact
          range, since we would have to calculate the range
          based on each one of the boxes. Anyway, it fits our needs...
          */
      $('#littleBoxes > div').not($currentBox).each(
        function() {
          var $ele = $(this);
          $ele.stop().animate({
            'top': (Math.floor(Math.random() *
              601) - 150) + 'px',
            'left': (Math.floor(Math.random() *
              601) - 150) + 'px',
            'opacity': 0
          }, 800, function() {
            $(this).hide();
          });
        });
      /* expand the clicked one;
          also, fadeIn the content (boxcontent)
          */
      var newwidth = 945;
      var newheight = 375;
      $currentBox.stop().animate({
        'top': '0px',
        'left': '0px',
        'width': newwidth + 'px',
        'height': newheight + 'px'
      }, 800, 'easeOutBack', function() {
        current = $currentBox.index();
        $(this).find('.boxcontent').fadeIn();
      });
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
#logo {
  display: block;
  height: 380px;
  width: 950px;
  background: #F7F7FF;
  background-image: url(http://thoseleftbehind.b1.jcink.com/uploads/thoseleftbehind/Images/amlogo.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px
}
.littleBoxes {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 343px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative
}
.littleBoxes > div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #F7F7FF;
  overflow: hidden;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #555;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #555;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #555;
  background-position: center center;
  z-index: 999
}
.littleBoxes div a.logobox {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 120%;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: Oswald, sans serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 90px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #F7F7FF;
  background-image: linear-gradient(right bottom, #111 5%, #2A2D34 50%, #111 95%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right bottom, #111 5%, #2A2D34 50%, #111 95%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right bottom, #111 5%, #2A2D34 50%, #111 95%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right bottom, #111 5%, #2A2D34 50%, #111 95%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right bottom, #111 5%, #2A2D34 50%, #111 95%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, right bottom, left top, color-stop(0.05, #111), color-stop(0.5, #2A2D34), color-stop(0.95, #111));
  outline: none
}
.littleBoxes div.boxcontent {
  height: 380px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 100%;
  color: #333232;
  background-color: #F7F7FF;
  border: 2px solid #F7F7FF;
  margin: 0;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #777;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #777;
  opacity: .9;
  display: none
}
.boxcontent .boxinfo {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #F7F7FF;
  width: 46%;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: justify;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: -20px
}
.boxcontent .boxstaff {
  float: right;
  width: 46%
}
.boxinfo b {
  font-size: 105%;
  text-shadow: #333232 0 1px 1px;
  background: linear-gradient(right bottom, #111 5%, #2A2D34 50%, #111 95%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent
}
.boxcontent div a {
  display: inline;
  background: transparent
}
.bg1,
.bg2,
.bg3,
.bg4 {
  background-repeat: no-repeat
}
.bg1 {
  background-image: url(../images/1.jpg)
}
.bg2 {
  background-image: url(../images/2.jpg)
}
.bg3 {
  background-image: url(../images/3.jpg)
}
.bg4 {
  background-image: url(../images/4.jpg)
}
.bg5 {
  background-image: url(../images/5.jpg)
}
#staffer h1 {
  display: block;
  margin-top: -20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: #333232 0 1px 1px;
  background: linear-gradient(right bottom, #111 5%, #2A2D34 50%, #111 95%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent
}
#staffer h2 {
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: -25px
}
#staffer img {
  margin: -20px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  transition: all, 1s;
  -moz-transition: all, 1s;
  -webkit-transition: all, 1s
}
#staffer img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
  filter: grayscale(0%)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<div id="logo">
  <div class="littleBoxes" id="littleBoxes">
    <div class="boxlink bg1" style="top:0px;left:0px;">
      <a class="logobox" href="">About</a>

      <div class="boxcontent">
        <p></p>

        <div class="boxinfo">
          <b>Those Left Behind is a zombie survival RPG</b> based in the fictional Massachusetts city of Acheron.
          <br>
          <br>In November of 2014, the dead began to rise and the human population found itself tested. Most major cities fell to the undead, but a few quarantine zones have managed to stay afloat due to military protection. Now the year is 2034 and, as you
          might expect, the times have twisted many people into hardened survivalists.
          <br>
          <br>Those in the quarantine zones are offered protection by what's left of the U.S. military, but it comes at the cost of many of their freedoms and dignities. Meanwhile, corruption from both the military and criminal organizations makes it difficult
          to live even within areas deemed safe.
          <br>
          <br>How will you survive in a world where you're one of those left behind?
        </div>

        <div class="boxstaff">
          <div id="staffer">
            <h1>Staff</h1>

            <h2>Amy</h2>
            <a href="http://thoseleftbehind.jcink.net/index.php?showuser=2" target="_blank">
              <img src="http://i.imgur.com/5HN9d6Z.jpg">
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bg5" style="background-position:-90px 0;top:0px;left:95px;"></div>

    <div class="bg5" style="background-position:-180px 0;top:0px;left:190px;"></div>

    <div class="bg5" style="background-position:-270px 0;top:0px;left:285px;"></div>

    <div class="bg5" style="background-position:0 -90px;top:95px;left:0px;"></div>

    <div class="boxlink bg2" style="top:95px;left:95px;">
      <a class="logobox" href="">Groups</a>

      <div class="boxcontent">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bg5" style="background-position:-180px -90px;top:95px;left:190px;"></div>

    <div class="bg5" style="background-position:-270px -90px;top:95px;left:285px;"></div>

    <div class="bg5" style="background-position:0 -180px;top:190px;left:0px;"></div>

    <div class="bg5" style="background-position:-90px -180px;top:190px;left:95px;"></div>

    <div class="boxlink bg3" style="top:190px;left:190px;">
      <a class="logobox" href="">News</a>

      <div class="boxcontent">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bg5" style="background-position:-270px -180px;top:190px;left:285px;"></div>

    <div class="bg5" style="background-position:0 -270px;top:285px;left:0px;"></div>

    <div class="bg5" style="background-position:-90px -270px;top:285px;left:95px;"></div>

    <div class="bg5" style="background-position:-180px -270px;top:285px;left:190px;"></div>

    <div class="boxlink bg4" style="top:285px;left:285px;">
      <a class="logobox" href="">Credits</a>

      <div class="boxcontent">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bg5" style="background-position:-270px -180px;top:0px;left:380px;"></div>

    <div class="bg5" style="background-position:-270px -180px;top:95px;left:380px;"></div>

    <div class="bg5" style="background-position:-270px -180px;top:190px;left:380px;"></div>

    <div class="bg5" style="background-position:-270px -180px;top:285px;left:380px;"></div>

    <div class="bg5" style="background-position:-270px -180px;top:0px;left:475px;"></div>

    <div class="bg5" style="background-position:-270px -180px;top:95px;left:475px;"></div>

    <div class="bg5" style="background-position:-270px -180px;top:190px;left:475px;"></div>

    <div class="bg5" style="background-position:-270px -180px;top:285px;left:475px;"></div>

    <div class="bg5" style="background-position:-270px -180px;top:0px;left:570px;"></div>

    <div class="bg5" style="background-position:-270px -180px;top:95px;left:570px;"></div>

    <div class="bg5" style="background-position:-270px -180px;top:190px;left:570px;"></div>

    <div class="bg5" style="background-position:-270px -180px;top:285px;left:570px;"></div>

    <div class="bg5" style="background-position:-270px -180px;top:0px;left:665px;"></div>

    <div class="bg5" style="background-position:-270px -180px;top:95px;left:665px;"></div>

    <div class="bg5" style="background-position:-270px -180px;top:190px;left:665px;"></div>

    <div class="bg5" style="background-position:-270px -180px;top:285px;left:665px;"></div>

    <div class="bg5" style="background-position:-270px -180px;top:0px;left:760px;"></div>

    <div class="bg5" style="background-position:-270px -180px;top:95px;left:760px;"></div>

    <div class="bg5" style="background-position:-270px -180px;top:190px;left:760px;"></div>

    <div class="bg5" style="background-position:-270px -180px;top:285px;left:760px;"></div>

    <div class="bg5" style="background-position:-270px -180px;top:0px;left:855px;"></div>

    <div class="bg5" style="background-position:-270px -180px;top:95px;left:855px;"></div>

    <div class="bg5" style="background-position:-270px -180px;top:190px;left:855px;"></div>

    <div class="bg5" style="background-position:-270px -180px;top:285px;left:855px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[The version in CodePen](http://codepen.io/karlen/pen/RNeqrm) is also updated.